# Heap Sort Questions

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, heapsort

I am working on a homework problem that involves a heap sort implementation in java. Here is what I have so far

```
public class HeapSort {

    public static void maxHeapify(int[] a, int i) {
        int largest;
        int l = 2*i;
        int r = (2*i)+1;
        if (l<=a.length-1 && a[l]>a[i]) {
            largest = l;
        }
        else {
            largest = i;
        }
        if (r<a.length-1 && a[r]>a[largest]) {
            largest = r;
        }
        if (largest != i) {
            int temp = a[i];
            a[i] = a[largest];
            a[largest] = temp;
            maxHeapify(a,largest);
        }
    }

    public static void buildMaxHeap(int[] a) {
        for (int i=(a.length-1/2); i>=1; i--) {
            maxHeapify(a,i);
        }
    }

    public static void heapSort(int[] a) {
        buildMaxHeap(a);
        for (int i=a.length-1; i>=1; i--) {
            int temp = a[0];
            a[0] = a[i];
            a[0] = temp;
            maxHeapify(a,1);
        }
    }
```

Here is a main I put together to test (with output)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] tester = {3,2,9,45,7,15,21,11,36};
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(tester));
    heapSort(tester);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(tester));
}

[3, 2, 9, 45, 7, 15, 21, 11, 36]
[3, 45, 36, 21, 9, 15, 2, 11, 7]
```

I am not currently getting any errors but the output is just a bit off. Any help is very much appreciated. Thanks!

*Edited to add sample output

Comment: `(a.length-1/2)` pretty sure its `a.length/2` in `BuildMaxHeap()`

Comment: Perhaps you meant to write `(a.length-1)/2`. Pay attention to order of operations...`a.length - 1/2 == a.length`.

Comment: made this change and tried changing it to a.length/2 with the same output. Something else must be going on. Thanks for the suggestions though!

Answer (score 2):

At a quick glance, I'd say you are missing a number of calls to maxHeapify(). It looks like you only maxHeapify() half of the heap (the half that ends in the rightmost branch), but not the rest. You must call maxHeapify() for all elements in a[0] to a[length/2].

You should move the recursive call to maxHeapify() out of the conditional for swapping. For the initial build of the heap, you must propagate all the way up to the root.
And you don't maxHeapify() the 'largest' element, but the one one level up the heap, so always `i/2`.

Answer (score 0):

```
    if (r<a.length-1 && a[r]>a[largest]) {
        largest = r;
    }
```

should be

```
    if (r<=a.length-1 && a[r]>a[largest]) {
        largest = r;
    }
```

I believe you also have to call `maxHeapify(a,0);` instead of `maxHeapify(a,1);` in the last loop. Apart from that the -1/2 ordering issue in the comments mentioned above. That should do the job.